# list showing index out of range even though there are entries present in the file

Tags: python

I am trying to print 'value' but after a while it throws out of index error. I have checked the location and there are many more entries present there

```
import pandas as pd
import os
import time
import datetime as datetime

path = "G:\ML\Investing\intraQuarter"

def Key_Stats(gather="Total Debt/Equity (mrq)"):
    statspath = path+'/_KeyStats'
    stock_list = [x[0] for x in os.walk(statspath)]
    #print('stock_list : ',stock_list[1:10])

    for each_dir in stock_list[1:]:
        each_file = os.listdir(each_dir)
        ticker = each_dir.split("_KeyStats\\")[1]

        if len(each_file) > 0:
            #parsing time from the html file
            for file in each_file:    
                date_stamp = time.strptime(file, '%Y%m%d%H%M%S.html')
                unix_time = time.mktime(date_stamp)
                #print(date_stamp, unix_time)
                full_file_path = each_dir+'/'+file
                source = open(full_file_path, 'r').read()
                value = source.split(gather+':</td><td class="yfnc_tabledata1">')[1].split('</td>')[0]
                print(ticker+":", value)
                time.sleep(0.1)


Key_Stats()
```

Comment: can you print out the value of source where it is failing?

Comment: aa: 52.71
aapl: 0.072
aapl: 0.07
aapl: 0
aapl: 0
aapl: 0
aapl: 0
aapl: 0
aapl: 0
aapl: 0
aapl: 0
aapl: 0..It fails after this even though there are more files available at current directory

Comment: I think it has something to do with consecutive 0s, I removed the 'appl' directory, it ran fine until it encountered consecutive 0s again for some other directory

Comment: @Msk do you have any idea about this issue?